# Route URL me agrega barra en Laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, paginación

En un sitio hecho con ***Laravel*** no me funciona la paginación.

En localhost funciona bien:

```
localhost:8000/comunidad?page=2
```

En mi servidor compartido en cambio agrega la barra /:

```
martinaquino.com/comunidad/?page=2.
```

La ruta es:

```
Route::get('/comunidad', 'Web\PageController@blog')->name('comunidad');
```

Mi htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

También probé entre estas dos variantes:

```
{{ $posts->render() }}
{{ $posts->links() }}
```

El error siempre es el mismo, no página a la siguiente página. Recarga la misma.

Por favor sería muy importante todo tipo de orientación.

Encontré una solución que fue creando una nueva ruta! aún sigo sin comprender que me afecto a esa ruta. Gracias a todos los que intentaron colaborar en la solución.

Comment: ¿Nadie sabe que puede ser?

Comment: por que cambiaste el .htaccess? probaste si funciona dejándolo tal cual lo trae Laravel? veo que no tienes las 3 líneas que siguen a [`# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/aa74fcb38f9f318159657ba5050eda62ec043b11/public/.htaccess#L12). Pregunto porque nunca he tenido que cambiar nada en ese archivo para deployar en un servidor.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Lo tuve que hacer para agregar https. Aúnque sólo lo copié de otro proyecto. Pero no sabría bien cómo funciona. Probé en dejarlo tal cuál lo trae laravel por default y tampoco me funciona. Voy a ver este link que me adjuntas. Agradecería todo tipo de sugerencia. Muchas gracias.

Comment: por que cambiaste el htaccess: ? bueno .. está bastante raro ¿cómo lo tienes en tu controlador?

Comment: Martin, no sé bien como es que agregaría https ese cambio en .htaccess, cuando me ha tocado implementar https siempre lo he hecho directamente en el servidor (nginx) con certbot, y no he tenido que cambiar nada en Laravel, pero pude hacerlo así porque tenía acceso a la configuración del server. El link que te pasé es al .htaccess de la última versión de Laravel, específicamente a esa línea que podría traducirse como "# Redireccionar barras diagonales finales si no es una carpeta.." y me pareció que puede estar relacionado con el problema que comentas.

Comment: Alex agradezco mucho tu dedicación. Me encontré con que tenía que solucionarlo de forma urgente y por lo tanto cree una nueva ruta y todo funciona en la nueva dirección. Aún no comprendo que me afecto la ruta pero por lo solventé así. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Pon el .htaccess como viene por defecto y para configurar https hazlo desde la configuración de apache o nginx, utilizando el puerto 443 y algún certificado como pueden ser los de certbot

saludos